# Invalid date value in csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, vbscript

I export data in csv format from sql server database. It contain 5 column. one column have date and time value. When i checked the date -time value i found date time value is in wrong format. I add the filter but filter not applied on some data. I try to format the data in same format but formatting did not applied on the data. I tried everything to fix the issue but it is not getting fix.

I have attached the sample data please check it from your end.

```
7/12/2013 14:50
8/12/2013 20:14
9/12/2013 11:38
10/12/2013 15:31
13/12/2013  12:45:50
13/12/2013  14:35:42
13/12/2013  14:37:40
14/12/2013  17:00:10
18/12/2013  14:57:35
```

Data started from 13/12/2013  12:45:50 are not getting change in date time format.

Comment: If you copy the above data and paste it in excel then fix the format of data. It is not getting fix.

Comment: This smells to me like a US/UK date format issue - which cultures are you running in?

Comment: Is US dates they have the month first, so you're actually saying on the 12th day of the 13th month I suspect that's your issue

Comment: the data comes from sql database. It is in UK format. My own keyboard is configured as US Eng. I tried to change it in UK format as well but it is not getting fixed. Only half of data is formatable rest are not.

Comment: The half which are formatted are probably the first 12 days of the month. You need to update your consuming application to cope with UK date format (or set SQL to export in US/ISO). I can't advise anymore without knowing where you're trying to import these into

Comment: Is there any to convert it after export from sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that your dates are in french format dd/mm/yyyy you can force them to datetime with the following line :

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("7/12/2013 14:50", "d/MM/yyyy HH:mm", $null)

[datetime]::ParseExact("13/12/2013  12:45:50", "d/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss", $null)
```

Be carefull in you case sometime you've got seconds and a double space between day and time.